# How do I solve this app startup error in heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku

Hey Guys please help me with this problem!
Thanks :D

OLD LOGS:

```
2018-10-02T06:47:43.191640+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.308759+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.191640+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.308759+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:58:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:58:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-10-02T07:03:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:03:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-10-02T07:09:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:54.741609+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:54.741609+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0c3d9616 by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-02T07:16:48.138432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_                                                                                                                                                             id=6aced25b-f8c4-460e-8c1b-8f8794d40d2f fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:16:48.457466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=dd99c34d-0bbc-46b8-b9c9-ee2418cf8cc4 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:16:48.493293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=47ec0871-d865-4ea4-93b1-d96e5782ccc2 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:18:52.707524+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user kailauber@                                                                                                                                                             icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:18:52.707524+00:00 app[api]: Set token config vars by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:19:58.616740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=f9116de7-d7f2-4354-b188-09624ed4c482 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:20:35.194420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=1ae1bc26-39a2-482a-87cc-12149d45a89d fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-10-02T07:20:35.382931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=01d7c808-b8ca-4c82-a4b4-b0697541264f fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= conect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-10-02T07:20:35.390361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=3e2ed998-d89f-4961-b629-0dadcb00c89d fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

NEW LOGS AFTER DYNO:

```
2018-10-02T06:47:43.191640+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.308759+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.191640+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:47:43.308759+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:58:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T06:58:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-10-02T07:03:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:03:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-10-02T07:09:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:54.741609+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:54.741609+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0c3d9616 by user kailauber@iclud.com
2018-10-02T07:09:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-02T07:16:48.138432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=6aced25b-f8c4-460e-8c1b-8f8794d40d2f fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:16:48.457466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web rocesses running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=dd99c34d-0bbc-46b8-b9c9-ee2418cf8cc4 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:16:48.493293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=47ec0871-d865-4ea4-93b1-d96e5782ccc2 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:18:52.707524+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:18:52.707524+00:00 app[api]: Set token config vars by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T07:19:58.616740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web rocesses running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=f9116de7-d7f2-4354-b188-09624ed4c482 fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= servce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T07:20:35.194420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=1ae1bc26-39a2-482a-87cc-12149d45a89d fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-10-02T07:20:35.382931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=01d7c808-b8ca-4c82-a4b4-b0697541264f fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-10-02T07:20:35.390361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=3e2ed998-d89f-4961-b629-0dadcb00c89d fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-10-02T08:01:08.132111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=0cf0fb63-b02b-43d8-90a2-3a6526d8c96d fwd="89.217.251.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T09:50:43.236146+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:50:43.236146+00:00 app[api]: Remove token config vars by user kailuber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:50:57.411848+00:00 app[api]: Set token config vars by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:50:57.411848+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:51:14.652913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=048ef97b-f342-47b6-9266-d77926934cc2 fwd="176.127.140.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T09:51:14.671402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=23759f86-fd20-442c-b8db-dfa3163140ab fwd="176.127.140.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T09:51:14.470107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=02385247-7c6f-4e6f-a6b8-b1c89e4e8a02 fwd="176.127.140.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T09:58:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:59:17.578544+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7161d06f by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:59:17.578544+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T09:59:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-02T10:00:07.539714+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user kailauber@icloud.com
2018-10-02T10:00:11.688081+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2018-10-02T10:00:12.363320+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-02T10:00:13.702632+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-02T10:00:13.704665+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed totarting
2018-10-02T10:00:13.690858+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-10-02T10:00:13.631854+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: node: command not found
2018-10-02T10:00:14.828142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trapnationbot.herokuapp.com request_id=7403214c-8e37-488c-b674-0b6255f8af52 fwd="176.127.140.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T10:00:18.760188+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2018-10-02T10:00:19.575651+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-02T10:00:21.292435+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-10-02T10:00:21.307843+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-02T10:00:21.213892+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: node: command not found
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post text as an image. Images can't be copied or searched, and users who use assistive technologies like screen readers can't consume them very well. Instead, paste the text directly into your question, select it, and click `{}` or press Ctrl+K. This will indent the text and SO will treat it as code.

Comment: Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577) You'll have much better luck asking a clear question as described in [ask].

Comment: Finally, the text you show in your screenshot doesn't appear to be complete. Please run `heroku logs` and show us a complete traceback.

Comment: @Chris I have added the code to the question.

Comment: @Chris **update** I have added the worker dyno and now a few of the errors are gone, I have posted the old logs and new logs in the question!

Comment: What does "after dyno" mean? A dyno is the thing that Heroku uses to run your code.

Comment: And what's in `bot.js`? Is your bot something that runs in a web server?

Comment: I recommend you create a ticket in the technical assistance of heroku, the personal experience is very good, respond quickly, often share some very good tips that can make the day easier. Then with the answer you can share it in this thread so that we can all help each other.